# Elasticsearch query error - [or] query malformed, no start_object after query name

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Can somebody explain me please what is wrong with this query? I need to convert this generated query from Elasticsearch 2 to Elasticsearch 6. In ES2 this one works well, but in ES6 it throws me an error: **[or] query malformed, no start_object after query name**. I am lost in it. OR is necessary cause there could be more conditions than this one.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "or": [
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "zalozcovia",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.meno": "\u013dubo\u0161"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.priezvisko": "Majgot"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.mesto": "Trnava"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [
        {
            "rok": "desc"
        },
        {
            "cislo": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES6 there is afaik no "OR" Query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-or-query.html). You should use a bool query and use there the "should" Part (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "zalozcovia",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "filter": [{
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.meno": "\u013dubo\u0161"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.priezvisko": "Majgot"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.mesto": "Trnava"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [{
            "rok": "desc"
        },
        {
            "cislo": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but SHOULD throws me the same error only insead of [or] is [should]

Comment: Don't add `or` inside the `should` part.

Comment: I dont. I change the OR to SHOULD.

Comment: can you show your corrected query? at least the error somehow shows, that your syntax is still not applicable. i think you should get rid of the first filter and switch or to should.

Comment: You removed FILTER level. I missed it. Without filter it works. But I am not sure if I can remove it from the query.

Comment: bool.filter is like bool.must without affecting score in ES6. i dont know, what ES2 was like. maybe you can describe what you want to get with this query.

Comment: Hmm if I add the BOOL level inside the FILTER it works.

Comment: well I guess you can also just remove the "or" part of your query and keep the filter, because you just have one statement in there (and "or" just affecting with 2 or more entitys).

Comment: I am little confused about the score. I thought filter is exactly the way how to not count the score.

Comment: i updated the answer so it uses filter as you wished instead of should

Comment: yes filter ignores the score. i think the query now should fit your needs

Comment: No the SHOULD is necessary cause the code is generated and there could be more conditions not only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189270/discussion-between-camo-and-richiek).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "filter-or" with should

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
              "should" : [
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "zalozcovia",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.meno": "\u013dubo\u0161"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.priezvisko": "Majgot"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "match": {
                                                "zalozcovia.mesto": "Trnava"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [
        {
            "rok": "desc"
        },
        {
            "cislo": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but I am not sure if I can remove Filter level from query. Filter should be little efficient cause it does not count a score. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure sir, But in your query above, seems, it doesn't need filter with or :) 
You can check this answer for must and filter difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43349478/2057653

Comment: I know but there could be more conditions than one.

Comment: you can add each condition to should array ? I don't get what is wrong?

Comment: Ok I have it. There should be one more BOOL level inside the FILTER. Thanks.