# Must returns more results than Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I checked this question [What is the difference between must and filter in Query DSL in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349044/what-is-the-difference-between-must-and-filter-in-query-dsl-in-elasticsearch) and read answers.

As far as I understood must and filter should return same result. Am I right? But when I change filter query to must, I receive more result? What I am doing wrong?

[image]

I compared filter and must query and got different result.

Comment: can you share your entire queries ?/

Answer (score 0):

**Must query** gives you some score that is used to add to the total score of the doc.

**Filter query** does not add any score. It is just used to decide whether a doc is returned or not in the result set.

By just looking at the screenshot of the query attached, when you change filter query to must query it starts adding some value to the total score of the doc.

Since you are using **min_score condition**, the must clause makes more docs exceed 0.2 score and hence more docs are returned in the final result set.

Rest things will be more clear when you share the complete query.